# Adjusting Chrome Bookmarks Bar via Intune

Tags: json, google-chrome, bookmarks, intune

I am trying to add individual bookmarks onto the bookmarks bar in Chrome via Intune. It works except I need the links to be on the Bookmarks bar and not in a folder on the bar.

The only JSON code that is provided makes it go into a Folder called "Managed bookmarks". I've tried various ways to force it to add the links outside of the folder onto the bookmarks bar but my json knowledge is not that great :(

Here's the code that I use in the configuration profile in Intune:

`[

```
{
    "toplevel_name":
},

{   "name": "StackOverflow",        
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",         
    "ShowOnBookmarkBar": true   
},
{   "name": "BBC News",         
    "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk",         
    "ShowOnBookmarkBar": true   
}
```

]`

Answer (score 0):

So I personally tried this on my test tenant and I realised that the "Managed Bookmarks" folder, which you could rename to any other suitable name like I did in mine (See attached screenshot), is derived from the JSON array you pass in the Managed Bookmarks setting. Trying to pass a single JSON string to display a single link did not work for me. You could also omit this part of the JSON : `{ "toplevel_name": }`  and still end up with the "Managed Bookmarks" folder. I think the best option currently is to rename the folder to something appropriate; (See my JSON script attached) [image: Bookmarks added to Chrome with Custom named Root folder]

```js
[{
    "toplevel_name": "Matucorp favorites"
  },
  {
    "name": "StackOverflow",
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
  },
  {
    "name": "BBC News",
    "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk",
  }
]
```